# CP sat solver approach for task assignment with pre defined task start end times

Tags: solver, cp-sat, c#

I spent some time trying to clarify the problem more succinctly.
I has a set of fixed tasks which are of a certain type/category and which can be allocated to a set of workers.
The tasks have predefined start times/durations and have an optional gap (i.e. 30) which must be honoured when the tasks are performed by the same worker.
The idea is to constrain worker allocation in the following ways

a) each task is performed by a single worker,
b) no worker can perform an overlapping task, and
c) no worker can be allocated to successive tasks of the same type/category without satisfying the leaving the required gap.

Constraint c) is to ensure that tasks which are deemed difficult/taxing are not allocated successively to the same worker. This is the concept /constraint that I am having difficulty in applying.

```
   public class Task
    {
        public Task(int taskId, int start, int duration, string type, int gap =30)
        {
            TaskId = taskId;
            Start = start;
            Duration = duration;
            Gap = gap;
            Type = type;
            Name = "T" + taskId + "S" + Start + "D" + duration;
        }
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public int Start { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public int Gap { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public string Type { get; }

    }

...
     Dictionary<int, Task> allTasks = new Dictionary<int, Task>();
        allTasks.Add(0, new Task(0, 0, 30, "obs2"));
        allTasks.Add(1, new Task(1, 0, 30, "obs2"));
        allTasks.Add(2, new Task(2, 0, 60, "obs4"));
        allTasks.Add(3, new Task(3, 60, 60, "obs4"));
        allTasks.Add(4, new Task(4, 120, 60, "obs4"));
        allTasks.Add(5, new Task(5, 180, 60, "obs4"));
        allTasks.Add(6, new Task(6, 240, 30, "obs4"));
...
IntervalVar[,] task_intervals = new IntervalVar[numNurses, numTasks];
Dictionary<(int, int), BoolVar> tasks = new Dictionary<(int, int), BoolVar>(numWorkers * numTasks);

//worker to task allocation
     foreach (int n in allNurses)
        {
            foreach (int s in allTasks.Keys)
            {
                tasks.Add((n,s), model.NewBoolVar($"tasks_n{n}s{s}"));
            }
        }

//No worker can perform overlapping tasks
 foreach (var worker in allNurses)
        {
            foreach (var task in allTasks.Values)
            {
                task_intervals[worker, task.TaskId] = model.NewOptionalIntervalVar(task.Start, task.Duration, task.Start + task.Duration, tasks[(worker, task.TaskId)], $"task[{task.TaskId}]");
            }
        }

        foreach (var worker in allNurses)
        {
            model.AddNoOverlap(
                (from task in allTasks.Keys
                 select task_intervals[worker, task]).ToList()
            );
        }

 // Each task is assigned to exactly one worker.
        List<ILiteral> literals = new List<ILiteral>();
        foreach (int t in allTasks.Keys)
            {
            
            foreach (int n in allWorker)
                {
                    literals.Add(tasks[(n, t)]);
                }
                model.AddExactlyOne(literals);
                literals.Clear();
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to ORSE. Would you please, what you mean by overlapping the tasks if you already know those start times and end times in advance? In this case, your problem can be simplified to assign workers based on your need. Would you elaborate more on the details of the problem by making a simple example? :)

Comment: A few quick questions come to mind. Are you committed to using a SAT solver versus an integer programming model/solver? Do you have a criterion for an "optimal" assignment, or are you just looking for any feasible assignment? Is it required that all tasks are staffed? Are there limits to how many tasks or how many hours a worker can be assigned?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I see that you added some additional details/clarification and then rolled back the changes. Why did you not leave the changes in place?

Comment: I have updated the question to hopefully provide more clarity. specifically the constraint required to ensure sufficient gaps between assigned tasks.